# The most prestigious journal in economics is publishing a plagiarized paper. What can be done about this?

Tags: plagiarism

The plagiarism was noted in an online forum frequented by economists. The editor of said journal is now accusing the site of sexism and flat out refuses to address the plagiarism accusation. What can be done?

Here's a summary of the situation

http://retractionwatch.com/2016/05/26/economists-go-wild-over-overlooked-citations-in-preprint-on-prenatal-stress/

Comment: Plagiarism (and other forms of academic misconduct) will be dealt with by the department or university of the author of the paper.  If there is an outside finding agency, maybe they would act.

Comment: This question is too short and too vague to be answered effectively.

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: Assuming you're referring to [this issue](http://retractionwatch.com/2016/05/26/economists-go-wild-over-overlooked-citations-in-preprint-on-prenatal-stress/), "flat out refuses to address the plagiarism accusation" is not an accurate characterization of the editor's response; you just disagree with how the editor addressed it (by allowing the authors to add citations). Anyways, to get a useful answer here, you'll have to be more specific in your question. What kind of action are you looking for here (what are you hoping to accomplish by said action)? Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: In addition to clarifying what kind of action you're looking for, you'll also have to clarify what your position is if you want to know what actions you can take. Are you a student? Full professor? Author of the original paper? Peer reviewer of the paper you consider plagiarized? Another editor at the same journal? Different actions are available to different people. Please [edit] your post to clarify

Comment: Also see [What else can I do if a journal editor ignores my report of plagiarism?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46989/what-else-can-i-do-if-a-journal-editor-ignores-my-report-of-plagiarism) and [Editor not taking action after I reported plagiarism. What steps can I take?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71110/editor-not-taking-action-after-i-reported-plagiarism-what-steps-can-i-take)

Comment: The write-up at Retraction Watch doesn't seem to give a fair overview of the situation at all. I'd recommend reading the original thread at Econ Job Rumors; it really is rather shocking.

Comment: @gnometorule I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not asking the OP to out themself by name, just to give the point of view from which they want an answer. Without that, the question is pretty vague. If the OP wants a particular point of view (including someone else's point of view, if the OP is e.g. just curious about what actions would be available to the reviewer in this situation), then the OP needs to specify that.